# use object list from form one in the form two

Tags: c#, winforms, list, object

I have two windows forms

```
 Form1 and Form2

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace myInterface
 {
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
       public Form2()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
 }
```

I have a class like this

```
  class item   
  {
     public string itemID { get; set; }
     public string itemName { get; set; }
     public decimal itemPrice{ get; set; }
  }
```

I have a list like this created and used in the Form1

```
List<item> myItems = new List<item>();
```

and I have added items to the myItems in an operation in Form1

I want to go through the myItems and get the item details in the myItems in the Form2.
How can I do that?
I know how to go through the list, showing how to have access to the list myItems from the Form2 is more than enough.

Comment: Pass it as argument to the constructor of form two (use ref)

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below :-

```
Public List<item> items;

 public Form2(List<item> items)
       {
           this.items = items;
           InitializeComponent();
        }
```

It means you are passing values to constructor of Form2 and you can access the list in Form2

Comment: Do I have to declare the list in the Form2?

Comment: I guess Yes, else how would you store the values you got from outside @Sahil?

Comment: All I have to do is making myItems list public and in the second form do I have to create a new list?

Comment: It doesn't work. It gives me following error,Form2 Doesn't contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.

Comment: you will have to pass list from where you are creating instance of Form2 @Sahil

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like taht

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
  private List<item> myItems = new List<item>();

  // Declare public property to let Form2 have access to myItems
  public List<item> MyItems {
    get {
      return myItems;
    }
  }
  ...
}
...

public partial class Form2 : Form {
  public void DoSomethingWithMyItems() {
    // First you have to find out Form1 if you don't have it yet
    Form1 myForm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().FirstOrDefault();

    // Form1 has not been found
    if (null == myForm)
      return;

    // Get the list from Form1 via public property MyItems
    List<item> myItems = myForm.MyItems;

    //TODO: Do what you want with myItems
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why do I have to declare it first private and then public?
When I declared like that it gives me a syntax error saying ambiguity..

Comment: declaring field public is a bad practice, that's why I've declared public property in addition to private field. Pay attention to casing: in `private List<item> myItems` myItems starts with lower case 'm' when in `public List<item> MyItem` MyItem starts with upper case 'M'

Comment: Still it gives me error inconsistent accessibility error,Systems.Collections.Generic.list<Myinterface.Items>is less accessible than MyInterface.Form1.MyItems

Comment: @Sahil: I see that your interface `MyInterface` is involved; what is it? Could you provide the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the list only if `Form1` is open.

Use following code:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form1 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().FirstOrDefault();
    if(form1 !=null)
    {
       //form1.myItems
    }
}
```

But make sure that `Form1` is open and `myItems` property is public.